# How do mods handle confessions of (trivial) vindictive downvoting?

Tags: discussion, down-votes

- A [question was posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17073833/how-can-i-get-the-selected-value-of-a-dropdown-list-created-via-echo/17073879#17073879)
- The first answer was bad, and I downvoted it, and it was quickly deleted
- myself and two others answered, and all three answers were downvoted at the same time (saw this happen).
- While watching the deleted answer's user card, I refreshed the browser and saw his rep drop by 6 points
- I called him out, and [he admitted to vindictively downvoting everybody](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17073833/how-can-i-get-the-selected-value-of-a-dropdown-list-created-via-echo/17073879#comment24692869_17073879).

I'm not requesting any action be taking, I'm simply wondering: Do mods actually *have* a recourse in such situations? This isn't really against any hard rules of the site, though I know vindictive downvoting is considered abusive by the community. Do they issue warnings for such behaviour? How are such warnings manifested?

Comment: Suspend his account for a year.

Comment: It happenned to me yesterday. I argued with a hi-rep user. And one of his fans downvoted many of my answers afterwards.

Comment: @user414076 That would be a squash-an-ant-with-a-low-orbit-ion-cannon solution...

Comment: @ʞunɥdɐpɐɥd The script is for someone downvoting a lot of posts from one user; it wouldn't reverse the case of voting down all of the answers to a question.  (It's actually very common to be legitimate votes in that case.  Many poorly worked, ambiguous, confusing, or just hard questions often generate a *lot* of low quality and/or wrong answers all deserving of downvotes.)

Comment: @meagar, so you're saying the ant would no longer be a problem. I agree.

Comment: @ʞunɥdɐpɐɥd: most of those were caught by the script. Also: get out of the habit of mentioning how you're voting in comments; it just encourages folks to fixate on voting instead of on your criticisms, which is probably *not* what you actually want.

Comment: @Shog9 Maybe it's my english but I don't understand what you mean by the second part of your comment.

Comment: @ʞunɥdɐpɐɥd: I'm referring to comments that begin with "-1 " and then follow with your actual critique... Or, for that matter, comments that contain text such as, "My downvote reflects the fact that..." - if you have a legit argument, it should stand on its own - you don't need to imply you're "enforcing it" with a vote.

Comment: @Shog9 Good thanks. Though you were explaining something to me.

Comment: If he downvoted 3 answers, wouldn't his rep drop by 3, not 6?

Answer (score 11):

> Do mods actually have a recourse in such situations?

Well, if someone's being an ass they can send him a nasty letter and (if necessary) [suspend](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125268/my-account-has-been-temporarily-suspended-what-does-that-mean).

If someone makes a *habit* of down-voting abusively, this is probably gonna happen - particularly if it generates flags.

In *extreme* situations, it would be possible to revert the voting, but this normally wouldn't happen; votes are the voters' to do what they want with. [Serial voting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me) would be crossing that line though.

Comment: I've always wondered how these nasty letters actually manifest themselves to the user. Is it just an email? Or is there some kind of hidden messaging system in the site, only usable by mods?

Comment: @meagar `"Or is there some kind of hidden messaging system in the site, only usable by mods?"` This.

Comment: The answer to that question is "yes", @meagar.

Comment: Really, so the mods would just pick an arbitrary post by the user and leave a comment? ... Disappointing. I was hoping for some kind of full-screen overlay "THE MODS HAVE SPOKEN" kind of affair.

Comment: @meagar: no, it's a completely separate messaging system that emails users *and* notifies them on-site.

Comment: Ah, I interpreted Servy's "This" to mean, literally, *these comments*. Less disappointed now.

Comment: It used to come via golden banner from the sky, but now it's just a little red dot in the corner.

Answer (score 3):

Members of the Community Team do have tools to reverse downvotes if they feel it's a case of voting fraud.  If they feel it's appropriate they could also send a mod message to the user leaving a permanent mark on their profile recording the instance of voting fraud.  Continued abuse could result in an account suspension.

Feel free to flag the comment in question as the means of drawing mod attention to the post.

Comment: The user in question is actually a pretty upstanding user, as far as I can tell. Just a random one-off spree of angry downvoting...

Comment: @meagar So then an account suspension would not be warranted, and even a mod message may not be needed.

Comment: Mods can't reverse or even (directly) see individual votes, only the community team.

Comment: @Servy I was more interested in what recourses were available to mods, in the general case where a user is abusing the voting system without really violating any rules, per se.

Comment: @meagar If they're abusing the voting system then they are, by definition, violating the rules.  If they're not abusing the voting system then it would simply be "doing something I don't like" and not "abuse".

Comment: @Kevin Oh, I knew they couldn't see votes, but I thought that there were certain [limited] cases in which they could reverse them when it was flagged by the system or something like that.  I'll edit.

Comment: We can ask the community team to reverse them, back when we could merge that effectively reversed them, but no more.